# Get all storage files in root storage folder and all items in all sub storage folders

Tags: uwp, storagefolder

Surely there is a simple way of getting all files within a folder and all sub-folders in UWP? I can't seem to find any examples of it anywhere. Below is my implementation which loops through loops for a finite amount of subfolders but it is a bit ridiculous and prone to error.

```cs
var libraryFolder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync("UserLibrary");


var subFoldersLayer1 = await libraryFolder.GetFoldersAsync();

                    var rootFiles = await libraryFolder.GetFilesAsync();

                    List<StorageFile> allFiles = new List<StorageFile>();
                    IEnumerable<StorageFile> allFilesForScanning = new List<StorageFile>();

                    foreach (var _file in rootFiles)
                    {
                        itemsFoundCounter++;
                        if (itemsFound != null)
                        {
                            itemsFound.Report(itemsFoundCounter);
                        }

                        allFiles.Add(_file);
                    }

                    foreach (var subFolderLayer1 in subFoldersLayer1)
                    {
                        var subFoldersLayer2 = await subFolderLayer1.GetFoldersAsync();
                        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await subFolderLayer1.GetFilesAsync();

                        foreach (var file in files)
                        {
                            itemsFoundCounter++;
                            if (itemsFound != null)
                            {
                                itemsFound.Report(itemsFoundCounter);
                            }

                            allFiles.Add(file);
                        }

                        foreach (var subFolderLayer2 in subFoldersLayer2)
                        {
                            var subFoldersLayer3 = await subFolderLayer2.GetFoldersAsync();
                            files = await subFolderLayer2.GetFilesAsync();

                            foreach (var file in files)
                            {
                                itemsFoundCounter++;
                                if (itemsFound != null)
                                {
                                    itemsFound.Report(itemsFoundCounter);
                                }

                                allFiles.Add(file);
                            }
// Goes on like this for a bit...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
 private async Task GetAllFiles(StorageFolder folder, List<StorageFile> allFiles, IProgress<int> itemsFound)
    {
        foreach (StorageFile file in await folder.GetFilesAsync())
        {
            if (file.FileType == ".ext")
            {
                allFiles.Add(file);

                if (itemsFound != null)
                {
                    itemsFound.Report(itemsFoundCounter);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (StorageFolder subfolder in await folder.GetFoldersAsync())
        {
            await GetAllFiles(subfolder, allFiles, itemsFound);
        }
    }
```